# On the minimal number of generators of a finite $p$-group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group of order $p^n$ and nilpotency class 2 with $|G'| = p^k$. Let $d_G$ denotes the minimal number of generators of $G$. If $d_G =n-k$, then how can I prove that $G^{ab}$ is an elementary abelain group?

What I've tried: By hypothesis, $|G^{ab}|=p^{n-k}$. Now since $G^{ab}$ is a finite abelian $p$-group, then by the Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, I have $G^{ab}\cong C_{p^{\alpha_1}}\times C_{p^{\alpha_2}}\times \cdots C_{p^{\alpha_t}}$, where $\alpha_1 +\cdots +\alpha_t =n-k$ and $\alpha_1 \geq \cdots \geq \alpha_t\geq 1$. To prove that $G^{ab}$ is elementary abelian, it is enough to show that $\alpha_1 =1$. By contrary, assume that $\alpha_1 >1$. Then $d_G =n-k=\alpha_1 +\cdots +\alpha_t >t=d_{G^{ab}}$. But I don't know why $d_G >d_{G^{ab}}$ is a contradiction. But by the @ArturoMagidin comment, if in nilpotent group, $d_G =d_{G^{ab}}$, the the proof is complete. But I don't know why "In any nilpotent group, a subset $X$ generates if and only if its image generates $G^{ab}$"? I was wondering if someone could help me about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In any nilpotent group, a subset $X$ generates if and only if its image generates $G^{\rm ab}$. Your question is equivalent to asking whether an abelian $p$-group of order $p^{n-k}$ that is minimally generated by $n-k$ elemens is elementary abelian, and the Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups trivially yields the answer.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq?cb=1

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you very much for the comment. Could you please give me a reference for the proof of the fact "In any nilpotent group, a subset $X$ generates if and only if its image generates $G^{ab}$"?

Comment: After almost 4 years here and 63 questions, surely you know that this question is poor and more likely to be closed than answered?

Comment: Dear @user172 , you are right. But I think this question is poor for you, not for me. I didn't ask for the answer, I did it just for hint or reference. Moreover, I didn't claim to be proficient in all mathematics "after almost 4 years here and 63 questions". I'm just learning. So I think if you can help someone, help him/her. Otherwise I can ask a kid in elementary school a question like your question as well, but what is the use for him/her! Anyway, thank you very much for your remark.

Comment: @M.Ramana I'm not saying "don't ask this question" and am not saying that after your time here you should know everything. I am saying that after your time here you should know *how* to ask a question - they *way* you asked this question is bad. (Which is what Alan's comment is saying.)

Comment: @M.Ramana It is a convention of this forum that you should supply context for your questions. In practice, you don't need to write much - just some information about where the question came from and you could tell us why you suspect that $G^{\rm ab}$ might be elementary abelian in this situation. There have been several instances recently of students sitting exams who have simply cut and pasted exam questions to this forum, hoping for a quick answer. Do you not agree that this practice is undesirable, and should be strongly discouraged?

Comment: @user1729 I have noting to say but you are right again. Thanks for your comments and guidance.

Comment: @M.Ramana Ok. Now edit your question to improve it. Say where it comes from or what you've tried (or read the link in Alan's comment in detail and figure out how to improve it).

Comment: @DerekHolt I absolutely agree. Whatever you and others are saying is completely true. I will try to ask my questions properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1729 Sure. Thank you.

Comment: The Frattini subgroup of a finite $p$-group is equal to $G'G^p$, and consists of all non-generators. Thus, a subset generates if and only if its image in $G^{\rm ab}$ generates.

Comment: So the answer to your question is yes, and you do not need the hypothesis that the group has class $2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Understood. Could you please me tell me that my proof for $d_G =d_{G^{ab}}$ below is right or not? Thank you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I appreciate you for nice comments.

Comment: @M.Ramana You have proved that none of the chosen generators of $G/G'$ is redundant, but that does not obviously imply that there is no smaller generating set of $G/G'$. Since you have not used the fact that $G$ is a $p$-group, you should not be suspicious! You really need to use the fact that $\Phi(G) = G'G^p$ in a finite $p$-group, so $G/\Phi(G)$ is elementary abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt I've used the fact the $\Phi (G)=G'G^p$ in finite $p$-groups, when I said that $x\in G^p G'=\Phi(G)$ (the set of all non-generator elements in $G$) while $x$ is a generator. In fact, $\{ xG'\; |\; x\in X\}$ is minimal generator set for $G/G'$ and since $|\{ xG'\; |\; x\in X\}|=|X|$, so $d_G =d_{G/G'}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right, but the point I was making is that you have not proved that there is no generating set of $G^{\rm ab}$ of size less than $|X|$. You have only proved that none of the generators in the set $\{xG': x \in X \}$ is redundant. So yes you are right, but you have not proved it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Understood. That's true. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you please tell me how I can prove $d_G =d_{G^{ab}}$?

Comment: That followsfrom $\Phi(G) = G^pG'$, which is a standard result for finite $p$-groups. Search for "Burnside Basis Theorem"

Comment: @DerekHolt "Burnside Basis Theorem" says: Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Then $\Phi(G) =G'G^P$. Also, if $[G: \Phi (G)] = p^r$, every set of generators of $G$ has a subset of $r$ elements which also generates $G$". This means that $r$  is the minimal number of generators of $G$?

Comment: @DerekHolt If so, then since $[G:\Phi (G)]=[G^{ab}:\Phi (G^{ab})]$ for a finite p-group, we can conclude that $d_G =d_{G^{ab}}$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

What I've understood: Let $X$ be a minimal generator of $G$, where $d_G =|X|$. Clearly, $G/G'=\langle xG' \; |\; x\in X\rangle$. To show that $\{ xG' \; |\; x\in X\}$ is  a minimal generator set for $G/G'$, assume that there exists $x\in X$ such that $xG'$ is a non-generator  in $G/G'$. Then $xG'\in (G/G')'(G/G')^p=(G/G')^p =G^pG'/G'$. So $x\in G^p G'$ which is a contradiction because $x$ is a generator in $G$. Then $\{ xG' \; |\; x\in X\}$ is a minimal generator set for $G/G'$. Then $d_G =d_{G^{ab}}$.